# To compare dates using html5, jquery, ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, date

I need to do a web-form. It must content a date filter, i.e. some items must be shown if its are created between one date and other date.
My form:

```
<form id="tweetshow" method="post" action="" >
  <p>
    Enter user_id: <input type="text" name="user_id" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Enter user last tweets amount: <input type="text" name="last_tweets_amount" />
  </p>
  <p>
    From date: <input type="date" name = "from_date" step=7 min=2014-09-08>
  </p>
  <p>
    To date: <input type="date" name = "to_date" step=7 min=2014-09-08>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="ShowTweets()"/>
  </p>
</form>
```

This is my java-script, which proccesses it:

```
<script>
  var test = document.forms['tweetshow'].to_date.value;
  ...
  success:function(response)
  {
    ...
    if((item.created_at <= test))
    {
      $("<article>", { id: item.id })
      .append($header, $text, $details)
      .appendTo("#tweets");
      alert(test);
    }
  }
  ...
</script>
```

The variable `"item.created_at"` consists a date, which is built, for example, how this pattern: `"Sun Oct 19 11:45:28 +0000 2014"`, but the date, which enters in form(it consists in variable `"test"`), builds as this pattern: `"2014-10-19"`. How to compare the dates correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = document.forms['tweetshow'].to_date.value;
test = new Date(test).getTime();
```

Convert to date object

```
if((new Date(item.created_at).getTime() <= test))
    {
      // Do something
    }
```